# Check if column is in decreasing order

Tags: r

I want to check if column X is in decreasing order and if there are two identical values in column X, see if the ties are broken by the alphabetical order of letters in column Y.

Here is what I have so far, which doesn't return anything:

```
for (ii in 1:length(data_frame)) {
    if (ii == 1 | ii == length(data_frame)) {
      next
    } 
    else if (data_frame[["columnX"]][ii] == data_frame[["columnX"]][ii+1]) {
      ifelse(!is.unsorted(data_frame[["columnY"]][c(ii,ii+1)]),
             return(TRUE), 
             return(FALSE))
    }
  }
```

EDIT: dput()

```
structure(list(Count = c(8184L, 8046L, 7988L, 7970L, 7771L, 7755L, 
7730L, 7650L, 7557L, 7428L), Name = c("Mary", "John", "Mary", 
"Mary", "Mary", "Robert", "Mary", "Mary", "John", "Mary")), .Names = c("Count", 
"Name"), row.names = c(4533L, 130862L, 3830L, 2456L, 6700L, 130863L, 
3150L, 5965L, 114094L, 5269L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Just provided sample data!

Comment: This means if there are two identical Count values like 12 followed by a 12, R can't order based on Counts anymore....so R looks at the next column (which happens to be a column with characters) and uses its order to "break" the tie and determine the order of the rows based on the alphabetical order.

Comment: Yes exactly Sathish

Comment: If its not in decreasing order, return FALSE. If it is, return TRUE

Comment: @JasonBaik Your sample data doesn't have `Count` value same but my answer will work in cases where `Count` is same in subsequent rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the column is in decreasing order: `TRUE` = decreasing order; `FALSE` = Increasing order or Ties present

```
x_diff <- diff(df1$Count)
d_order <- if( all(sign( x_diff ) == -1) ) TRUE else FALSE
d_order # [1] TRUE
```

Check if ties present in column x and then go to column y, and check if the tied rows are in decreasing order. `TRUE` for decreasing order in column Y; `FALSE` for increasing order or ties in column Y; `NULL` for no ties present in column X.

```
t_order <- if( any( duplicated( df1$Count ) ) ){
  lapply( with(df1, Count[ duplicated(Count) ] ), function(x){
    temp <- with(df1, Name[ Count == x ] )   # loop is used to iterate over multiple ties with different values (Example : 12 and 12; 15 and 15)
    all( temp[-length(temp)] > temp[-1] )
  } )
} else NULL

t_order # NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` can be achieved using `lead` and `summarise`.

The approach is to first find difference between current row and next row. If that difference is greater than `0` that mean `decreasing order`. If difference is `0` than check for alphabetical comparison of `Name` column (current vs next) will decide `decreasing` order.

Finally if all values of `DecOrder` are in `TRUE` will indicate `Count` is in decreasing order.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(DiffCount = Count - lead(Count, default=0)) %>%
  mutate(DecOrder = ifelse(DiffCount == 0, Name > lead(Name), DiffCount > 0)) %>%
  summarise(IsDesc = all(DecOrder))

#Result
#  IsDesc
#1   TRUE
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Count = c(8184L, 8046L, 7988L, 7970L, 7771L, 7755L, 
7730L, 7650L, 7557L, 7428L), Name = c("Mary", "John", "Mary", 
"Mary", "Mary", "Robert", "Mary", "Mary", "John", "Mary")), .Names = c("Count", 
"Name"), row.names = c(4533L, 130862L, 3830L, 2456L, 6700L, 130863L, 
3150L, 5965L, 114094L, 5269L), class = "data.frame")
```